# Docker installation fails on CentOS 7.4

Tags: linux, centos, docker, centos-7

Installing docker on Centos 7.4 fails.

i ran the command to install some dependencies :

```
# yum install device-mapper-persistent-data lvm2
```

And i got the result :

`Error: Package: 7:device-mapper-event-1.02.140-8.el7.x86_64 (ultra-centos-7.4-base) Requires: device-mapper = 7:1.02.140-8.el7 Installed: 7:device-mapper-1.02.146-4.el7.x86_64(installed) device-mapper = 7:1.02.146-4.el7 Available: 7:device-mapper-1.02.140-8.el7.x86_64 (ultra-centos-7.4-base) device-mapper = 7:1.02.140-8.el7`

OS Information :

> uname -a
> => Linux mail 3.10.0-862.3.2.el7.x86_64 #1  x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Redhat release :

> cat /etc/redhat-release
> => Centos Linux 7.4.1708 (Core)

Comment: Hi d41k1 & welcome to StackExchange. The site asked me to review your first post, and I've made a few inline suggestions. Please take a moment to insert your commands and responses, formatted as code. This will help the community provide a great answer.

Comment: Ok thank you ! i update my post

Comment: I don't know if my post isn't good. It's my first time, please if i have to correct something to get answer to my problem help me. Thank again !

Answer (score 0):

The error message explains:

Package: 7:device-mapper-event-1.02.140-8.el7.x86_64 (ultra-centos-7.4-base) Requires: device-mapper = 7:1.02.140-8.el7

Installed: 7:device-mapper-1.02.146-4.el7.x86_64(installed) device-mapper = 7:1.02.146-4.el7

Available: 7:device-mapper-1.02.140-8.el7.x86_64 (ultra-centos-7.4-base) device-mapper = 7:1.02.140-8.el7

It appears the package you are trying to install (device-mapper-persistent-data) requires the package device-mapper = 7:1.02.140-8.el7.

You have device-mapper installed, but your installed version is device-mapper-1.02.146-4.el7.x86_64

The error is also telling you that you can install the available version. In CentOS, you use the yum command to install, upgrade, and remove packages. Look into yum command examples, searching for centos device mapper to get started.